# Echo in FaceTime video call

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, audio, macos, facetime

Here is my setup:

- User A: iPad Air, iOS8
- User B: (1) iPad Air 2, iOS9, (2) MBP 15", El Capitan

FaceTime between User A <-> User B (1) works just fine. When FaceTime video call is initiated between User A <-> User B (2) (same network, same time, can be just after first call is finished) this is when problem starts.

User A all of a sudden can hear his own voice echoing in his speakers and garbled a lot to the point where it's almost impossible to have two way conversation. User A can hear voice from User B just fine in both cases.

Any ideas what's going on here? I have a suspicion that it started with El Capitan upgrade but I can be wrong. The craziest part is how changes in User B environment can affect User A side of communication.

Comment: Maybe this depends on the fact the you are not using headphones on your MacBook?

Comment: User B is not using headphones on either iPad or MBP. In reality it's multiple people at the same time from user B side, so headphones are not an option.

Comment: In iPads and iPhones there is a system that balance the input sound from two microphones and this avoid echo problems. I'm not sure that MacBookPro have the same system and therefore using only one microphone, if echo is present it can not be removed!